# Consulta mysql con datetime no devuelve resultados

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando averiguar cómo puedo obtener el resultado de una consulta en función de la fecha actual, para ello tengo en `c#` una especie de dashboard de crm con dos `datetimepicker` y un par de botones para indicar la fecha.

En mi tabla tengo un campo llamado *created* que es de tipo `dateTime`, y cuando le hago la consulta para que me devuelva los valores que hay tal día, me sale cero. La consulta es esta:

```
private void btnHoy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dtpEndDate.Value = DateTime.Now;

        string startDate = dtpStartDate.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
        string endDate = dtpEndDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss");

        cm = new MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM customers WHERE @created", con);
        con.Open();

        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@created", dtpEndDate);

        dr = cm.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read())
        {
            lblVentas.Text = dr[0].ToString();
        }
        dr.Close();
        con.Close();

    }
```

He probado tambien cambiando la estructura de la fecha en los dos strings superiores pero sigue sin funcionar, tambien poniendo `created = NOW()`, pero no he sido capaz de recuperar valores.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Pero ese query esta basicamente mal.. no podes poner where y un dato.. como lo tenes.. te falta el campo con el cual comparar ese dato...

Answer (score 0):

Amigo mira si lo que mencionas que en tu BD tienes un campo de tipo `DateTime` este guarda la fecha con la hora, minutos, segundos (2022-05-26 00:00:00.000). en caso de que guardes en otro formato anexa alguna información extra.

En tu consulta esta mal te falta poner si es `= < >` etc. algo así.

```
WHERE = @created
```

Si  tu haces una consulta tu valor debe coincidir con el dato de tu campo datetime en tu bd y sera imposible que sean iguales debido a la hora, lo que debes hacer es buscar solo por fecha  o generar un rango entre las horas.

Como recomendación puedes convertir tu columna datetime de la BD en yyyy--mm-dd y no te tome en cuenta la hora.

El `CONVERT` especificas que sea `date` ya que este devuelve un `YYYY-MM-DD` y luego indicas a que columna de tu tabla y al final pones la comparación.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM customers WHERE CONVERT(date,created)=@created;
```

En este caso comparas fechas con el formato `YYYY-MM-DD` ignorando la hora y así especificas una fecha para tu parámetro `@created` ya sea actual o elegida por usuario.

Comment: Muchas gracias, justo he solucionado el problema con la consulta CONVERT, ya que como dices, me tenia en cuenta tanto el dia como la hora, cuando solo quería que me pillará el día.

Comment: Excelente, que bueno que te funciono , recuerda marcar las respuestas como aceptadas para futuros usuarios con problemas iguales